# Angular karma-jasmine: Included file cannot be found by XHR/GET

Tags: angularjs, node.js, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have included an existing project file in my karma.conf.js files array:

```
files : [
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/js/**/*.js',
  'test/unit/**/*.js',
  'bower.json',
  'app/data/file.json',
],
```

I know the file has been matched because I do not get a warning that
`WARN [watcher]: Pattern <pattern> does not match any file.` I changed that line to a known non-existent file and back to double check.

My base path is the project root:

```
basePath : '../',
```

When Angular's controllersSpec.js runs, I use an XHR GET to synchronously load the file, but I get a HTTP 404. Where is the file?

```
//Synchronously GET the test data
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'app/data/file.json', false);
req.send(null);

var testData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
```

Then, in the test shell, I see:

```
WARN [web-server]: 404: /app/data/file.json
<user agent> ERROR
  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
  at <path to project>/test/unit/controllersSpec.js:12
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're trying to load a local file with a GET request; depending on what port or host your server is running on, it may not be able to load it up via a relative path. Try instead pointing it to the full URL path including protocol and domain name, e.g.:

```
//Synchronously GET the test data
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'http://servername.com/app/data/file.json', false);
req.send(null);

var testData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
```

Comment: Can you even hit that url in your browser?

Comment: No, it's not the right port. I can't load any included files. The port in the config file is the port that's used for browser capture (which displays the Karma test page).

Comment: Yes, when the Angular program runs the file is accessible. This is only a problem when I run the test with karma-jasmine.